# phpunit test case in magento 2

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit

I want to add the phpunit test case for the following file, as I am new to magento, don't know how to add the test case in the magento module.

```
<?php

namespace Test\Rma\Block\Adminhtml\Rma\Edit\Tab\Items\Grid\Column\Renderer;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Context;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Status extends \Magento\Rma\Block\Adminhtml\Rma\Edit\Tab\Items\Grid\Column\Renderer\Status
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    public function __construct(
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Rma\Model\Item\Status $itemStatus,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        parent::__construct($context, $itemStatus, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Renders status column when it is editable
     *
     * @param   DataObject $row
     * @return  string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CamelCaseMethodName)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ElseExpression)
     */
    protected function _getEditableView(DataObject $row)
    {
        $options = $this->getStatusManager()->getAllowedStatuses();
        $selectName = 'items[' . $row->getId() . '][' . $this->getColumn()->getId() . ']';
        $isAllowed = $this->authorization->isAllowed('Test_Rma::return_approval');
        if (!$isAllowed) {
            $html = '<select name="' . $selectName . '" class="admin__control-select required-entry" disabled>';
        } else {
            $html = '<select name="' . $selectName . '" class="admin__control-select required-entry">';
        }
        $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        $html .= '<option value=""></option>';
        foreach ($options as $val => $label) {
            $selected = $val == $value && $value !== null ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
            $html .= '<option value="' . $val . '"' . $selected . '>' . $label . '</option>';
        }
        $html .= '</select>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !!!